Forced to discard digital signature after opening and immediately saving an Macro-Enabled Excel file
so recently I've made some changes to a .xlsm Excel file and then digitally signed it.
I then opened the .xlsm Excel file and saved immediately without doing anything. An error message saying that "You have modified a signed project. You do not have the correct key to sign this project. The signature will be discarded. ..."
This is very puzzling as I did not make any changes to the macros at all between opening and saving the file.
I'm trying to find out what is causing this issue and I've narrowed it down to these changes I've made before digitally signing the file:

Resizing UserForms
Changing RowSource Property of a Dropdown Control in an UserForm
Changing the Caption Property of an UserForm
Adding the code "Calculate" in my VBA Macros

I've also discovered some really weird behavior regarding UserForms

Viewing the UserForm's interface in the VBA editor [either clicking View Object or just double-clicking the UserForm] automatically forces you to discard the Digital Signature upon saving even though no changes were made
After the changes, the UserForm periodically resizes on its own randomly and without warning, requiring me to manually adjust it via the VBA Editor

My own's guess is that by opening the .xlsm Excel file, the UserForm somehow got edited in the background, causing Excel to conclude that I've modified a signed project while I have done nothing.
Anybody can help point me in the right direction, and possibly explain this error? Thanks a lot!

I wonder if it changes anything if you do Debug - Compile VBA Project before signing?

Or try this: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/digitally-sign-your-vba-macro-project-956e9cc8-bbf6-4365-8bfa-98505ecd1c01#:~:text=One%20way%20to%20prevent%20users%20from%20accidentally%20changing%20your%20macro%20project%20and%20invalidating%20your%20signature%20is%20to%20lock%20the%20macro%20project%20before%20applying%20the%20signature.
